# Default cube in the Opening of Blender Software

Tags: modeling

Normally when we open blender software a default cube appears. However, in my case, last worked file is opening in place of the default cube page. It may happen that I have clicked somewhere and as a result this change has been made. I want that default cube while opening Blender software.

Comment: A lot of settings can be changed and saved for startup in the _Startup File_. If you want a default cube, after starting Blender, add the cube, then go to the menu _File_ > _Defaults_ > _Save Startup File_. This also saves settings like render engine, render samples etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Press *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Load Factory Settings*.
- Then *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Save Startup File*.

Note that it will erase all settings! To avoid that, do this:

- Press *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Load Factory Settings*.
- *File* -> *Save* - save this in file system.
- Restart Blender, open saved file
- Then *File* -> *Defaults* -> *Save Startup File*.